# Obter ID da transação do PayPal no Ionic

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova

Estou usando PayPal em meu projeto seguindo [esta documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/).

Minha dúvida é: como faço para receber o ID da transação após o pagamento efetuado? Meu código é:

```
this.payPal.init({
      PayPalEnvironmentProduction: ''
      PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'mySandbox',
    }).then(() => {
      this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({
        acceptCreditCards: false,
        languageOrLocale: 'pt-BR',
        merchantName: (this.produto.nom_produto),
        merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: '',
        merchantUserAgreementURL: ''
      })).then(() => {
        let detail = new PayPalPaymentDetails('1.00', '0.00', '0.00');
        let payment = new PayPalPayment('1.00', 'BRL', 'Produto', 'Sale', detail);
        this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((response) => {
          console.log('pagamento efetuado');
          this.createCode();
          let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom' });
          toast.setMessage('Pagamento efetuado com sucesso');
          toast.present();
        }, () => {
          console.log('erro ao renderizar o pagamento do paypal');
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

Na documentação diz:

```
this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then(() => {
      // Successfully paid

      // Example sandbox response
      //
      // {
      //   "client": {
      //     "environment": "sandbox",
      //     "product_name": "PayPal iOS SDK",
      //     "paypal_sdk_version": "2.16.0",
      //     "platform": "iOS"
      //   },
      //   "response_type": "payment",
      //   "response": {
      //     "id": "PAY-1AB23456CD789012EF34GHIJ",
      //     "state": "approved",
      //     "create_time": "2016-10-03T13:33:33Z",
      //     "intent": "sale"
      //   }
      // }
    }, () => {
      // Error or render dialog closed without being successful
    });
```

Mas não sei exatamente como adicionar esses detalhes (`id`, `create_time`, etc) em meu projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que a resposta esteja no formato JSON informado, você pode capturar o id da seguinte forma:

```
this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((res) => {
  console.log('pagamento efetuado');
  this.createCode();
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom' });
  toast.setMessage('Pagamento efetuado com sucesso');
  toast.present();

  let id = res.response.id;
  console.log(id);

}, () => {
  console.log('erro ao renderizar o pagamento do paypal');
})
```

Comment: Obrigado por respoonder, eu consigo receber o ID da transasção que é como: PAY-72J79963NM5333513WLQVCVNHOW mas quando eu verifico no histórico de transações do Paypal Developer, o ID de transação é parecido com: 3CC23774TG6379823 .  Como eu posso sincronizar esses valores diferentes? para confirmar um pagamento via QR Code? os ID's são diferentes.

Comment: Nunca usei a api do PayPal, mas pelo que eu entendi, para receber os detalhes da transação, você precisar usar esse método: [https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_get](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_get), informando o código "PAY-....". Acredito que o valor que você está buscando é o id da autorização.